# Where to start understanding chemical principles of human body?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, book-recommendation

I have no background in chemistry.

What is a good way to start understanding principles of human body - how it works, determine which meals are good or bad for health. Maybe it is not just chemistry, but some other fields, too. I just want to know how human body works, lets say - improve health - but on my own. Knowing just that this is not good for health is not enough for me. I want to build deep knowledge.

I want to know how it is functioning at the lower level (based on chemistry).

Where to start?

(sorry for my incompetence)

Comment: Biochemistry requires a strong understanding of (general) biology, molecular cell biology, chemistry and organic chemistry. I recommend beginning with basic chemistry if you're not already familiar.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start from the chemistry upwards I'd recommend you to either look into a biochemistry textbook (buy or borrow one/get a used one, since they are quite expensive) or look for some (online) courses in that field.

The textbooks I know from university studies are:

- Biochemistry (Stryer, Berg, Tymoczko) [possibly downlaodable from [here]](https://archive.org/details/BiochemistryStryer7th)
- Biochemistry (Voet & Voet)
- Lehninger Principles of Biochemistry (Cox, Nelson)

The MIT offers quite a few (free!) [online courses](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/find-by-topic/#cat=science&subcat=biology&spec=biochemistry) and there seem to be quite a number of biochemistry ones (I haven't looked into any of them, but I reckon the MIT courses aren't too bad).

Comment: I did not find the prerequisities for Biochemistry (Stryer, Berg, Tymoczko). What should I know to start read this book?

Comment: @JúliusMarko If I remember correctly (I don't have anything at hand right now) the books contains a few chapters with basic information about the underlying chemistry. Maybe try the link I added to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Nicolai offered book (and other ressource) recommendations in biochemistry (+1). However, you might want to start with some very introductory general biology. For this purpose the Campbell Biology book is one of the best.

You can find the [11th edition here on Amazon.ca](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0134093410) but it is quite pricy but if you can accept a slightly older edition (that will still teach you a lot) such as [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0558497403), then you can get away for much cheaper.